# FF4j Web console is not displayed properly

Tags: spring-boot, ff4j

I am new to FF4J and started with hello world application.
I wrote a sample spring boot project and added dependency for ff4j-spring-boot-starter and ff4j-web modules in my pom.xml.

However, when I run the application, the FF4J web console is displayed distracted.
Below is my pom.xml and web console screenshot.

[image]

Below is the web console that I see

[image]

I am not sure what is the mistake here.
Please check and help. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same issue too. Were you able to solve this? I noticed the following in the server logs:
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"

Answer (score 1):

Please add "/" at end of the URL in browser. So if, the `ff4j-console` url is `http://localhost:8080/ff4j-console` it should be changed to `http://localhost:8080/ff4j-console/`
This resolved my problem.

Comment: thx that helped) extra slash at the end ;)